# useradd PAM authentication failed

Tags: centos, pam, useradd

I needed to customize useradd command so i [downloaded shadow-utils](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/shadow-utils/shadow-4.1.4.tar.gz/e1072df927bfb4410ee4dfe26dd81a17/) source package. Using configure-make i was able to compile the source , binary was generated (configure prefix) at custom location (/home/user1/Download/shadow-utils/sbin).

now trying to use 
**./useradd john** 
i get :

> configuration error - unknown item 'PASS_MIN_LEN' (notify administrator)
>   useradd: PAM authentication failed

also 
**ldd /home/user1/Download/shadow-utils/sbin/useradd**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2970d000)
>>  libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00002add214e7000) 
>>  libpam_misc.so.0 => /lib64/libpam_misc.so.0 (0x00002add216f6000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00002add218fa000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00002add21b1d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003273400000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003274000000)
>>  libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x000000327c400000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003273000000)
>>  libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00002add21d3e000)
```

**ldd /usr/sbin/useradd**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc6eda000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00002b478d16b000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00002b478d38f000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00002b478d5ae000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b478d7b6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b478db4b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003273000000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00002b478dd4f000)
```

clearly my version of useradd uses PAM library , freeb13 but does not use libacl, libattr .
Though after commenting out PASS_MIN_LENGTH from /etc/login.defs , the **configuration error** is gone , but the authentication failed error still remains.

It seems that i need to build useradd without libpam , but is there a way out of present situation ? Hints / help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Generally for making such modifications to standard programs it's best you download your distribution's source package for that program, make your modification, and then use the normal building procedure to build a package. That way you don't have such differences in how a package is configured. You can then install the result; just care take that upgrades don't replace your version (in Debian I'd put the package "on hold" usign aptitude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while configuring , used flags : `--without-libpam --without-sha-crypt` . The `useradd` command was successfully creating users now.